# AppendChild() isn't a function javascript

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I have a problem with a Drag and Drop code.

This is a code

```
const p = document.querySelectorAll(".p")
const s = document.querySelectorAll(".s")

p.forEach(parrafo => {
    parrafo.addEventListener("dragstart", event => {
        parrafo.classList.add("dragging")
        event.dataTransfer.setData("id", parrafo.id)
    })

    parrafo.addEventListener("dragend", () => {
        parrafo.classList.remove("dragging")
    })
})

s.forEach(seccion => {
    seccion.addEventListener("dragover", event => {
        event.preventDefault()
    })

    seccion.addEventListener("drop", event => {
        const id_parrafo = event.dataTransfer.getData("id")
        const parrafo = document.getElementById(id_parrafo)
        seccion.appendChild(id_parrafo)
    })
})
```

When I want to change the

element to the other container with the drop event, I get an error in the console "Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node'".